# Blur View background turns opaque after view controller has loaded

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

My social media app has a Feed view controller embedded in a navigation controller with a search button as a bar button item. Upon clicking the search button, a search view controller embedded in a different navigation controller is pushed with a blurred background. This segue is done via Storyboard. The blurred background sustains for a half second before turning opaque. My assumption is that once the search view controller  loads, the root view controller changes from the Feed view controller to the Search view controller.

Is there any way for me to sustain the blurred Feed view as the background of the Search view controller? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: After trying this out on a simple separate Xcode project, it seems that the issue specifically occurs with the Show/Push segue (once again, made via storyboard) but does not with the other segue styles. Is there a workaround to this?

[Simplified project storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeuII.png)

[Simplified project blurred background issue GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLGGP.gif)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I would present search VC, on click of search button action, instead of pushing using a separate navigation controller. This could help avoid the hierarchy conflict that you are facing currently.

Comment: I appreciate your reply but I don't think it's an issue related to the separate navigation controller. Please see the new media files I just uploaded of my separate simplified Xcode project emulating the same issue.

Comment: Since you are pushing a search view controller into navigation controller, your search view controller is now displayed with navigation controller as the background. For that scenario, you could just set the required background color to be shown behind the search view controller on load of search vc ( self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow ). This will give the blurred look and feel that you might be looking for. Alternative approach would be to present search VC instead of pushing. Again, that depends on your design and requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Girish! That would work for the simplified demo app I included in the attachment, but for the main app I'm trying to implement this with, the root view controller has dynamic data that I'd like to keep under the blurred background. Additionally, for whatever reason, when I do a modal (present) segue, the search bar container does not appear in the search VC.